# Scraping table with multiple pages throwing AttributeError

Tags: loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

I am trying to loop through multiple pages on [this website](https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement?page=1) I am scraping with BS.

```
pg = soup.find('ul', 'pagination')
current_pg = pg.find('li', 'active')
next_url = current_pg.findNextSibling('li').a.get('href')
```

Any ideas on how to solve the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'?

Answer (score 0):

To get to the next page, try to parse the `href=` from `<a rel="next">` tag. If the `<a>` doesn't exist, exit the loop:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement?page=1"

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    # parse the table and print some data:
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
    print(url)
    print(df.tail())
    print("-" * 80)

    next_link = soup.select_one("a[rel=next]")
    if not next_link:
        break

    url = next_link["href"]
```

Prints all the 20 pages:

```
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement?page=19
    S/N            Suit No                                                           Case Title                    Parties                                   Respondents                    Justice       Judgment        Date
95   96  NICN/ABJ/273/2014                       CHUKUEZI CHINEDU GOODWILL VS SIRAJ NIGERIA LTD  CHUKUEZI CHINEDU GOODWILL                             SIRAJ NIGERIA LTD  HON. JUSTICE E.D. E ISELE  view judgment  1970-01-01
96   97  NICN/ABJ/302/2012      BASIL ONYEBUCHI OKORO VS NIGERIA NATIONAL PETROLEUM CORPORATION      BASIL ONYEBUCHI OKORO        NIGERIA NATIONAL PETROLEUM CORPORATION  HON. JUSTICE E.D. E ISELE  view judgment  1970-01-01
97   98  NICN/ABJ/340/2013                            CHINEKWU NNENNA UDOKWU VS ZENITH BANK PLC     CHINEKWU NNENNA UDOKWU                               ZENITH BANK PLC  HON. JUSTICE E.D. E ISELE  view judgment  1970-01-01
98   99  NICN/ABJ/202/2013                IBRAHIM MUSLIM AYOADE VS NIGERIA BOTTLING COMPANY LTD      IBRAHIM MUSLIM AYOADE                  NIGERIA BOTTLING COMPANY LTD  HON. JUSTICE E.D. E ISELE  view judgment  1970-01-01
99  100  NICN/ABJ/246/2013  MR. MAHA ISIAKA ABU VS SKYE BANK (FORMERLY MAINSTREET BANK LIMITED)        MR. MAHA ISIAKA ABU  SKYE BANK (FORMERLY MAINSTREET BANK LIMITED)  HON. JUSTICE E.D. E ISELE  view judgment  1970-01-01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement?page=20
    S/N           Suit No                                                                                                     Case Title                   Parties                                                                              Respondents                                                                         Justice       Judgment        Date
26   27  NICN/CA/141/2013                                                 ENGR. PATRICK EDET OQUA VS ATTORNEY-GENERAL, CROSS RIVER STATE   ENGR. PATRICK EDET OQUA                                                      ATTORNEY-GENERAL, CROSS RIVER STATE                                               HONOURABLE JUSTICE E. N. AGBAKOBA  view judgment  1970-01-01
27   28  NICN/LA/243/2013                                                                       Emmanuel Fagbamila V University of Lagos        Emmanuel Fagbamila                                                                      University of Lagos                                                      Hon. Justice P.O Lifu (JP)  view judgment  0000-00-00
28   29    NIC/LA/03/2011  Sunday Olufelo VERSUS Schlumberger Anadrill Nigeria Ltd. . Schlumberger Support Nigeria Ltd.Schlumberger Ltd.            Sunday Olufelo  Schlumberger Anadrill Nigeria Ltd. . Schlumberger Support Nigeria Ltd.Schlumberger Ltd.  Hon. Justice B. B. Kanyip - Presiding Judge Hon. Justice O. A. Obaseki-Osaghae  view judgment  0000-00-00
29   30  NICN/LA/291/2012                                                       CAPTAIN SOLOMON J. GAMRA V CHANCHANGI AIRLINES (NIG) LTD  Captain Solomon J. Gamra                                                            Chanchangi Airlines (Nig) Ltd                                               HON. JUSTICE O.A. OBASEKI-OSAGHAE  view judgment  0000-00-00
30   31   NICN/CA/75/2013                                                                                        MR. MATTHEW EBONG UDO V     MR. MATTHEW EBONG UDO                                                     NATIONAL EXAMINATIONS COUNCIL (NECO)                                                 HON.JUSTICE O.A OBASEKI-OSAGHAE  view judgment  0000-00-00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because your selector does not match anything on the page you are trying to scrape.

The website you are trying to scrape contains 20 pages; you can just edit the link you are using for each request.

This goes to all the pages on the website and collects all the links from the tables.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for x in range(1,21):

    link='https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement?page={}'.format(x)
    web_info=requests.get(link).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(web_info,'lxml')

    #finding the table body on the page
    table=soup.find('tbody')

    #collecting all the rows
    rows=table.find_all('tr')

    #now you can examine each row for links

    for row in rows:
        link=row.find('a').attrs['href']
        print(link)
```

Comment: That's an interesting method. I didn't know that. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you even need `bs4` here and even `requests` but the reason why i used it is to persist the same session.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        params = {
            'page': 1
        }
        allin = []
        while params['page']:
            r = req.get(url, params=params)
            df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={'id': 'mytable'})[0]
            if 'next' in r.text:
                params['page'] += 1
                allin.append(df)
                continue
            params['page'] = False
        final = pd.concat(allin, ignore_index=True)
        print(final)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://nicn.gov.ng/judgement')
```

Output:

```
      S/N                     Suit No  ...       Judgment        Date
0       1            NICN/ABJ/67/2021  ...  view judgment  2021-10-14
1       2            NICN/ABJ/62/2021  ...  view judgment  2021-10-07
2       3          NICN/ABJ/304M/2020  ...  view judgment  2021-10-05
3       4           NICN/ABJ/240/2018  ...  view judgment  2021-07-28
4       5  SUIT NO. NICN/ABJ/185/2018  ...  view judgment  2021-07-14
...   ...                         ...  ...            ...         ...
1895   96           NICN/ABJ/273/2014  ...  view judgment  1970-01-01
1896   97           NICN/ABJ/302/2012  ...  view judgment  1970-01-01
1897   98           NICN/ABJ/340/2013  ...  view judgment  1970-01-01
1898   99           NICN/ABJ/202/2013  ...  view judgment  1970-01-01
1899  100           NICN/ABJ/246/2013  ...  view judgment  1970-01-01

[1900 rows x 8 columns]
```